# How to improve processing speed of google cloud vision api?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, ocr, google-vision

On my website I am taking a photo and storing it to Google Storage and right after saving the url (of the location in storage) to firestore database. Upon the creation of a document in firestore, firebase functions are called, which use vision api to detect text on the image  (the vision api uses the link to the image from firestore).
This process is taking quite a lot of time (5 seconds when it's quick, sometimes also over 10), so I was wondering whether there is a way to optimise this process to improve the processing speed.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Vision can receive parallel requests, and would get it done faster. You can also include more than 1 image in a [single annotate request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate).

If you just want to send the requests into the API fast and retrieve the results sometime later, you could use [asyncBatchAnnotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/asyncBatchAnnotate).

You may want to check [this example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detecting_text_in_a_local_image) and then use threads in your preferred programming language for sending/receiving parallel operations.

Additionally, there's a guide on [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) for optimizing the perfomance of the Cloud Functions that you can also check and follow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have a look at all of the links. My webapp works similarly to google lens (but I only use OCR and I don't need parallel requests), but I was wondering how does google lens work so fast? Is there a way to make my webapp as fast? I looked at the best practices you sent and am using all of them.

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question with regards to Google Lens, and how you can relate that through your application that uses Google Cloud Vision API.